# how to put elements out between screen in html

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html and css, I want to copy web: https://techtalk.vn/ to study help improve skill of me. I want to put two images out between screen in html, css. I hope everybody help me
or give me keyword, please!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tech Talk | Xu hướng công nghệ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header of webpage -->
  <header>
    <img src="img/logoretina.png">
    <img src="img/buoi1-dai-png-20180407110019.png">
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Easiest solution: use a table and set the images in two columns within the same row.

Comment: @FDavidov easiest solution is probably surround the two images with a div and give it a `display: flex;`

Comment: What does `between screen` mean?

Comment: @AbidHasan, well, I guess we should not argue about **TASTE**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rows and columns.

For example, you can do something like this using bootstrap, just change the paragraph tags with whatever you need to use it for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p>Testing 1!!!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Testing 2!!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It really isn't necessary to include 3 new libraries just for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make your codes like following codes

```css
/*add following code in your demo.css*/
body{width:80%;margin:0 auto;}
header{margin:50px 0}
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.block{width:49.5%;height:150px;}
.block img{width:100%;display:block;height:100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Tech Talk | Xu hướng công nghệ</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Header of webpage -->
 <header>
  <div class="block left">
   <img src="https://techtalk.vn/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/techtalk-siliconvalley.jpg">   
  </div>
  <div class="block right">
   <img src="https://techtalk.vn/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/techtalk-blog.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```